# Multiple lines added to vim line by line

Tags: bash, vim, automation, scripting, line

Can you please help add multiple lines of txt to the file via bash script through vim?

I tried this:

```
vim -c "3 s/^/
         add-this-line1
         add-this-line2
         add-this-line3/" -c "wq" /var/www/html/webserver/output_file.txt
```

But, the output of the file looks like this:

```
3 add-this-line1 add-this-line2 add-this-line3
```

What I want to do is, add the lines one by one FROM the line 3 in the `output_file.txt` not at the line 3 one next to another.

Comment: If you really really want to do this with vim, you might ask at [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Could you add a sample of the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a job for [ed](/questions/tagged/ed), IMO

```sh
seq 10 > file

ed file <<END_ED
3a
first
second
third
.
wq
END_ED
```

For those new to `ed`, the line with the dot signals the end of "insert mode".

`file` now contains:

```
1
2
3
first
second
third
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: First of all thank you, this works with the normal text. I am trying to insert a script into another script using this method, but ed executes that script before it appends it to another one, thus it writes totally different values. Do you know what can I add do add the script to another script via ed or any other tool maybe?

Comment: You'll want to ensure the here-doc is quoted, so that the shell does not touch it. That's easy to do: quote the here-doc "word" like this: `ed file << 'END_ED'` -- that's all you need to do.

Comment: glenn jackman, thank you very much sir works like a dream! You saved my day... I am new at the bash/linux, and I spent quite some number of hours to figure this out, but I could not do it. Again, thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to do it via vim, I believe you need to insert new lines in your substitution:

```
vim -c "3 s/^/add-this-line1\radd-this-line2\radd-this-line3\r/" -c "wq" /var/www/html/webserver/output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ex` or `ed` if available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' '3a' 'foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'more' . 'w output_file.txt' | ex -s input_file.txt
```

Replace `ex` with `ed` and it should be the same output.

---

Using a bash array to store the data that needs to be inserted.

```
to_be_inserted=(foo bar baz more)

printf '%s\n' '3a' "${to_be_inserted[@]}" . 'w output_file.txt' | ex -s inputfile.txt
```

- Again change `ex` to `ed` should do the same.
- If the `input` file needs to be edited in-place then remove the `output_file.txt` just leave the `w`.

---

Though It seems you want to insert from the beginning of the line starting from line number `"3 s/^/`

---

Give the `file.txt` that was created by running

```
printf '%s\n' {1..10} > file.txt
```

---

A bit of shell scripting would do the trick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

start=3

to_be_inserted=(
 foo
 bar
 baz
 more
)

for i in "${to_be_inserted[@]}"; do
  printf -v output '%ds/^/%s/' "$start" "$i"
  ed_array+=("$output")
  ((start++))
done

printf '%s\n' "${ed_array[@]}" ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

---

Output

```
1
2
foo3
bar4
baz5
more6
7
8
9
10
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if in-place editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` if you don't want to see the output.